# How to use this.refs for a list of child components

Tags: reactjs

I have a list of `<Child />` component, then I used an array `this.state.infos` to generate these child components. How can I use `this.refs` to get a specific child component?

NOTE: `this.state.infos = ['tom', 'mike', 'julie'];` for example.

```
export default class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      infos: {},
    };
  }

  // ignore logic for this.state.infos
  // ...

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          {[...this.state.infos].map((info) => {
            return <Child
              ref={info}
            />
          })}
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: for that you have to store the ref of all the child components, and that is not a good idea, can you explain why you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5):

For your approach, simply write

```
this.refs.tom
this.refs.julia
```

etc...

But note that this is considered legacy API, and you shouldn't use this any more.

 A better way is

```
 refsCollection = {};
 render() {
    return (
        <div>
          {[...this.state.infos].map((info) => {
            return <Child
              ref={(instance)=>{this.refsCollection[info] = instance;}
            />
          })}
        </div>
    );
  }
```

> React supports a special attribute that you can attach to any
>   component. The ref attribute takes a callback function, and the
>   callback will be executed immediately after the component is mounted
>   or unmounted.

The callback receives the child DOM element as the parameter, which you can then assign to a property in your parent component object. In the code above, notice how we assigned "instance" to "this.refsCollection[info]"

Of course in your case, because you defined the Child component yourself, it's not really a standard html DOM element, so the callback parameter is actually a mounted instance of your Child component object.

And then you access the mounted component instances using:

```
this.refsArray['tom']
this.refsArray['julia']
```

For more information, see this link:
https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: Also, consider moving whatever operation you're doing with the ref to inside the child component itself. This will make your code more modular. If what you're doing with the ref requires updating some data/state in parent, consider a callback prop on the child that manipulates data in the parent.